# Generating adaptors for higher-kinded interfaces

Tags: scala, scalaz, scala-macros, scala-cats

I often find myself in a scenario where I have defined an interface like so:

```
trait FooInterface [T[_]] {
  def barA (): T[Int]
  def barB (): T[Int]
  def barC (): T[Int]
}
```

I then write a few different implementations each typed on the Higher Kinded Type that makes the most sense for that particular implementation:

```
object FooImpl1 extends FooInterface[Option] { ... }
object FooImpl2 extends FooInterface[Future] { ... }
object FooImpl3 extends FooInterface[({type X[Y] = ReaderT[Future, Database, Y]})#X] { ... }
```

All implementations are perfectly valid, all return their results wrapped in a particular Higher Kinded Type.

I then often come to writing some business logic, let's say that in the block of logic I am working with is using `Future` as a context, I might write something like this:

```
val foo: FooInterface[Future] = ???

def fn (): Future[Int] = Future { 42 }

val result: Future[Int] = for {
  x <- foo.barA ()
  y <- foo.barB ()
  z <- foo.barC ()
  w <- fn ()
} yield x + y + z + w
```

The above code would work really well with `FooImpl2` however the other implementations do not slot in directly.  In this scenario I always wind up writing simple adapters:

```
object FooImpl1Adapter extends FooInterface[Future] {
  val t = new Exception ("Foo impl 1 failed.")
  def barA (): Future[Int] = FooImpl1.barA () match {
    case Some (num) => Future.successful (num)
    case None => Future.failed (t)
  }
  def barB (): Future[Int] = FooImpl1.barB () match {
    case Some (num) => Future.successful (num)
    case None => Future.failed (t)
  }
  def barC (): Future[Int] = FooImpl1.barC () match {
    case Some (num) => Future.successful (num)
    case None => Future.failed (t)
  }
}

case class FooImpl3Adapter (db: Database) extends FooInterface[Future] {
  def barA (): Future[Int] = FooImpl3.barA ().run (db)
  def barB (): Future[Int] = FooImpl3.barB ().run (db)
  def barC (): Future[Int] = FooImpl3.barC ().run (db)
}
```

Writing adapters is fine but it involves a lot of boilerplate, especially for interfaces with lots of functions; what's more is that each method gets the exactly same adaptation treatment for each method.  What I really want to do is `lift` an adaptor implementation from an existing implementation, only specify in adaption mechanism once.

I guess I want to be able to write something like this:

```
def generateAdapterFn[X[_], Y[_]] (implx: FooInterface[X])(f: X[?] => Y[?]): FooInterface[Y] = ???
```

So I could use it like so:

```
val fooImpl1Adapter: FooInterface[Future] = generateAdapterFn [?, Future] () { z => z match {
  case Some (obj) => Future.successful (obj)
  case None => Future.failed (t)
}}
```

The question is: How could I write the `generateAdapterFn` function?

I'm not really sure how to approach solving this, or if there are other common patterns or solutions to my problem.  I suspect that to write the `generateAdapterFn` function I desire I would need to write a macro?  If so how might that be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a natural transformation from `X` to `Y` (what you called `X[?] => Y[?]`). In Cats is called a `FunctionK` (with the popular type alias `~>`).

You could define a natural transformation between `Option` and `Future` as :

```
import cats.arrow.FunctionK
import scala.concurrent.Future

val option2future = new FunctionK[Option, Future] {
  def apply[A](opt: Option[A]): Future[A] = opt match {
    case Some(obj) => Future.succesful(obj)
    case None      => Future.failed(new Exception("none")) // t ??
  }
}
```

With the [kind projector compiler plugin](https://github.com/non/kind-projector/) this could be written more concise as :

```
val opt2fut = λ[FunctionK[Option, Future]]{
  case Some(obj) => Future.succesful(obj)
  case None      => Future.failed(new Exception("none")) // t ??
}
```

Your `generateAdapter` function could then look like :

```
import cats.~>

def generateAdapter[X[_], Y[_]](implx: FooInterface[X])(f: X ~> Y): FooInterface[Y] =
  new FooInterface[Y] {
    def barA: Y[Int] = f(implx.barA)
    def barB: Y[Int] = f(implx.barB)
    def barC: Y[Int] = f(implx.barC)
  }
```

You should then be able to create a `FooInterface[Future]]` as :

```
val fooFuture = generateAdapter(FooImpl1)(opt2fut)
```

Unrelated, you might be interested to read something about the [free monad](http://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/freemonad.html), which is used to solve similar problems as the one you are facing now.

Comment: Awesome, that's really helpful, it much more formally specifies what is happening.  In scenarios where there are many varied implementations of a given interface the generateAdapter fn will save writing a lot of boilerplate.

Comment: Perhaps there are two questions here, the first of which you've answered nicely, but to follow on from this, practically the code written when defining the generateAdaptor function is rather prescriptive, this is especially true for an interface that has many more functions than the one in the example.  Is there a way to avoid writing this directly and instead generating the implementation?  Perhaps reflection...

Answer (score 1):

Keep the code polymorphic for as long as possible. Instead of

```
val result: Future[Int] = for {
  x <- foo.barA ()
  y <- foo.barB ()
  z <- foo.barC ()
  w <- fn ()
} yield x + y + z + w
```

write

```
import scalaz.Monad
import scalaz.syntax.monad._
// or
import cats.Monad
import cats.syntax.all._

def result[M[_]: Monad](foo: FooInterface[M], fn: () => M[Int]): M[Int] = for {
  x <- foo.barA ()
  y <- foo.barB ()
  z <- foo.barC ()
  w <- fn ()
} yield x + y + z + w
```

This way, you avoid writing adapters for `FooInterface` altogether and only transform the final value (via a natural transformation (see Peter Neyens' answer) or also quite easily directly).

Answer (score -1):

Expanding on Peter Neyen's answer (which I've marked as correct as it answers the important part of my question), here's a proof of concept for how generate the adapter at runtime using reflection:

```
def generateAdapterR[X[_], Y[_]](implx: FooInterface[X])(implicit
  f: X ~> Y): FooInterface[Y] = {
  import java.lang.reflect.{InvocationHandler, Method, Proxy}
  object ProxyInvocationHandler extends InvocationHandler {
    def invoke (
      proxy: scala.AnyRef,
      method: Method,
      args: Array[AnyRef]): AnyRef = {
      val fn = implx.getClass.getMethod (
        method.getName,
        method.getParameterTypes: _*)
      val x = fn.invoke (implx, args: _*)
      val fx = f.getClass.getMethods ()(0)
      fx.invoke (f, x)
    }
  }
  Proxy.newProxyInstance(
    classOf[FooInterface[Y]].getClassLoader,
    Array(classOf[FooInterface[Y]]),
    ProxyInvocationHandler
  ).asInstanceOf[FooInterface[Y]]
}
```

Ideally it would be possible to type this function on `T[_]` as well, `T` being the type of the interface, so the function could be use to generate adaptors for any higher kinded interfaces at runtime.

Something like:

```
def genericGenerateAdapterR[T[_], X[_], Y[_]](implx: T[X[_]])(implicit
  f: X ~> Y): T[Y[_]] = ???
```

Not really sure if that would be how to write it though...

I think the ideal solution would be to have a compiler plugin that generates the code in Peter Neyen's solution, avoiding reflection and avoiding boilerplate.

Comment: If anyone knows of a better, safer way to write the reflection code above, specifically when it comes to dealing with runtime higher kinded types, I'd love to see how to handle it properly.